# How do you explain to the Product Owner that an error in a Web app is due to a browser quirk?

Tags: communication, errors

Web browsers are imperfect machines.

So let's say you came across an error. You might search your code to find the problem, and then failing that, you turn to online research that indicates the error isn't because of an error in your code but some error or other unexpected quirk in a correctly-configured browser.

Your product owner will want to know why the software doesn't work as expected. What do you tell them?

Comment: You tell them the truth, what else? And be prepared for the PO's next question "Is there a workaround for the specific issue (ideally one with no other unwanted side effects?)" and in case the answer is yes *"How much effort does this workaround mean?".

Comment: ... and notice, this site is for softwareengineering issues, not for pure communication issues in your team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's hard here.

> This is due to the differences between web browsers; it occurs only with browser X (when user has plugin Y installed) (when user is in private browsing mode) (when user is doing a handstand) (delete as appropriate). I've tested it with browsers A, B and C and with browser X when doing a somersault and we don't see this behaviour.
>
> How important is it that we fix this? We can certainly look at it if it is, let's stick a ticket on the backlog.

Comment: Guessing there is a browser support (non-functional) requirement. If this is happening on one of the browsers/versions that is "supported" then this is arguably a bug/defect.

Comment: One possible fix might be to move the browser from the "supported" to the "unsupported" list if the bug can't be worked around, and possibly check for unsupported browser versions where appropriate. But the gist is : tell them the truth.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner another one, although it isn't really a fix, but it may be a better long-term solution: file a bug report with the browser developers. Then if/when the browser devs fix the issue, you can refactor your code so it only applies for certain versions of the browser.